# Does unused tables in from clause impact performance of query?

Tags: sql, sybase

I am forming query dynamically .One thing I have noticed if  query has unused table  in 'FROM' clause  it is impacting performance. Just want to know is this behavior is  correct ? I am using SYBASE DB.

EDIT
unused table means  I have included it in from clause but I am not using it in where clause

Comment: what do you mean by "unused?"  What for is your query taking?  Typically if a table is in the query, it is being "used" by the database, whether you return any data that is in that table.

Comment: realistically if the table you're hitting against is truly unused (i.e. you're not using it to link to other tables and pull back data, and it's not an intermediate table to connect other pieces of related information, and you're also not pulling back values in the select statement) then it should be removed, as this will still have an impact on the query speed (exactly how much of an impact depends on a few things, such as if the table in question is properly indexed, and how much data it contains)

Comment: What you are doing is called Cartesian product. so if the unused table is not empty, you would got lot more rows and since you are not selecting anything from the unused table, they will all be duplicates. you may be doing distinct to eliminate duplicates which will further slow down the query

Answer (score 1):

Technically, SQL is a *descriptive* language rather than a *procedural* language.  That means that a SQL query describes the result set, but the engine is free to execute the query however it likes.

So, it is possible that a SQL optimizer might optimize away references to tables.  One extreme example of tis is Google's BigQuery which caches the results of queries.  Often a query cache is used for the second time a query runs -- the results are re-used instead of re-calculated.

In practice, though, basically all SQL engines (if executing the query) will process the tables in the FROM clause (either directly or through indexes).  There might be some SQL engines that will optimize away some references (say, a `left join` to a table on the primary key of the second table where no columns are used).

As a general rule, though, you can expect that adding more tables will affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. It assumes you needed that JOIN since it's in your query (either as a filter or some other reason). If it is simply a join (ie: comma separating the tables) with no WHERE condition, then performance will greatly be impacted as it will perform a cartesian or cross product on your results.

From Sybase docs:

> A cross product join returns a result set that produces all possible
>   combinations of rows from the two tables. The number of rows in the
>   result set is the product of the number of rows in the first table and
>   the number of rows in the second table.
>
> Example The FinancialData and FinancialCodes in the sample database
>   contain financial data for a fictitious company. Both tables have a
>   code column that you can use to join the two tables.
>
> The following SELECT statement lists all the data in the
>   FinancialCodes and FinancialData tables:
>
> SELECT * FROM FinancialCodes, FinancialData

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38159.1540/doc/html/san1281545626162.html